# Reusing HttpRequestMessage in Polly retry policies

Tags: c#, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

An `HttpRequestMessage` object can only be used one time; future attempts to use the same object throw an exception. I'm using Polly to retry some requests and I'm hitting this issue. I know how I can clone a request, there are plenty of examples on SO, but I can't figure out how to clone a request and send that new request whenever Polly retries. How can I accomplish this?

These are my policies, for reference. This is a Xamarin app. I want to retry a few times in case of network failures, and if the response is unauthorized I want to re-auth with saved credentials and try the original request again.

```
public static PolicyWrap<HttpResponseMessage> RetryPolicy
{
    get => WaitAndRetryPolicy.WrapAsync(ReAuthPolicy);
}

private static IAsyncPolicy WaitAndRetryPolicy
{
    get => Policy.Handle<WebException>().WaitAndRetryAsync(4, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}

private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> ReAuthPolicy
{
    get => Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(x => x.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        .RetryAsync((_, __) => CoreService.LogInWithSavedCredsAsync(true));
}
```

This doesn't work because of the `HttpRequestMessage` reuse, but it's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "some_endpoint")
{
    Content = new StringContent("some content")
};

request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

var policyResponse = await ConnectivityHelper.RetryPolicy
    .ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => _client.SendAsync(request)).ConfigureAwait(false);

// handle outcome
```

Comment: See [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260060/retrying-httpclient-unsuccessful-requests/48255857) especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260060/retrying-httpclient-unsuccessful-requests/35183487#35183487). Putting the retry in a DelegatingHandler avoids the cannot-reuse problem. If ASPNET Core and u can wait till 2.1 RTM, consider the new [IHttpClientFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1). If so see [Polly's doco](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) also.

Comment: @mountaintraveller Thanks, I somehow hadn't seen that one. I'm not sure how to combine it with the policies I already have though, I'm having trouble grasping how the Polly policies should all work together. (This is a Xamarin app, though I think the question is generic enough so I didn't include that.)

Comment: Polly doco on IHttpClientFactory discusses [when multiple policies are in use](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#applying-multiple-policies). This covers if applying multiple policies with the DelegatingHandler approach without IHttpClientFactory. For discussion of the concept see [Steve Gordon's blog](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers). If pre ASPNET Core 2.1, you have to create the chain of DelegatingHandlers manually.

Comment: If your query is generally about the behaviour when combining Polly policies, see [Polly wiki on PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap)

Comment: @mountaintraveller Oh, I think I understand now, the missing part in my head was how the `DelegatingHandler` worked. From what I understand, it's essentially middleware for the `HttpClient`, correct? So instead of manually calling my Polly policy each time, I configure the whole thing once and pass it to the `HttpClient` constructor? That makes things so much easier. Now I guess my question is how I can combine the `DelegatingHandler` approach with the behavior of `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync`. This is a Xamarin app, by the way.

Comment: Yes, DelegatingHandler is middleware for the HttpClient.  There isn't a way to combine ExecuteandCaptureAsync() with that - that is, inside a DelegatingHandler.  ExecuteandCaptureAsync() changes the return type of the execution; but middleware can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

The code to throw `InvalidOperationException` if an `HttpRequestMessage` is reused is a validation step within `HttpClient` itself.

[Source code link](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e7b9db69533dca155a33f96523875e9c50445f44/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L628-L634)

```
private static void CheckRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (!request.MarkAsSent())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.net_http_client_request_already_sent);
    }
}
```

[Source code link](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs#L193-L196)

```
internal bool MarkAsSent()
{
    return Interlocked.Exchange(ref sendStatus, messageAlreadySent) == messageNotYetSent;
}
```

You can put the polly retry policy in a `DelegatingHandler` and that works. It also provides a nice SoC (separation of concerns). If, in future, you want to *not* retry or change retry behavior, you simply remove the `DelegatingHandler` or change it. Note to dispose off the `HttpRequestMessage` and intermediate `HttpResponseMessage`s objects. Here is one that I use with good results ([retry policy](https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/1f99bd7919e3883121785181702a18dcd2cc5d41/src/rm.DelegatingHandlers/ExponentialBackoffWithJitterRetryHandler.cs)).

Your question is an open-ended, and generally SO is not good for those ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). But here goes. I call this a "reactive" approach as it uses the token right up until its ttl, and fetches the new one. Note that this doesn't incur 401s by using the token ttl.

```
# gets token with its ttl
tokenService: iTokenService
    # use retry policy in DH here
    httpClient
    string getTokenAsync():
        # calls out for token
        # note: tokens typically have a ttl

# returns cached token till its tll, or gets a new token which is then cached
cachedTokenService: iCachedTokenService
    tokenCached
    tokenTtl
    iTokenService
    
    string getTokenAsync():
        # returns tokenCached or gets a new token based on ttl
        # note: fetches with some buffer before ttl to avoid failures on edge
        # note: buffer as 2x http timeout is good enough

# DH that adds the cached token to the outgoing "work" request
tokenHandler: delegatingHandler
    iCachedTokenService
    task<response> sendAsync(request, ct):
        # gets token, and adds token to request header

# worker service
workService: iWorkService
    # uses tokenHandler DH
    httpClient
    workAsync():
        # ...
```