# Polly Retry All Exceptions Except Specific Condition

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, resiliency

Is there a way in Polly to retry all exceptions apart from those which are specified.. for example:

```
var p = Policy
    .Handle<HttpListenerException>(e => !(e.NativeErrorCode == 1))
    .Or<Exception>()
    .RetryAsync();
```

Here i have picked a slightly contrived situation where i would want to **NOT** retry when the `NativeErrorCode == 1`?

I initially hoped that this will retry if any value other than 1, and any other Exception dealt with by the `.Or<Exception>()` ..

What is actually happening, is that the `.Or<Exception>` will also catch the `NativeErrorCode == 1`, even though it was excluded from above? I think..

One option i considered, but not tested... (no error checking ;p)

```
var p = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>(e => SomethingMoreComplex(e) == true)
    .RetryAsync();

private bool SomethingMoreComplex(Exception e)
{
    if (e is HttpListenerException t)
    {
        if (t.NativeErrorCode == 1) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

is that threadsafe? :|

Comment: There's lots of ways to write this. I think the cleanest way is `.Handle<HttpListenerException>(e => e.NativeErrorCode != 1).Or<Exception>(e => !(e is HttpListenerException))` (that is, simply exclude `HttpListenerException` from the most inclusive check). The *shortest* way is probably `.Handle<Exception>(e => (e as HttpListenerException)?.NativeErrorCode != 1)`, but that's unnecessarily cryptic.

Comment: ah yes, i like that. My equivalent to e.NativeErrorCode != 1 is in reality a bit complex, but this will probably work fine... i will check how (un)readable it get! :)

Comment: +1 to @JeroenMostert 's.  Re thread safety: Polly policies themselves are fully thread-safe. And your `SomethingMoreComplex(...)` predicate isn't sharing any state outside the scope that could make it non-thread-safe. So, LGTM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check string content of response before retrying with Polly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835992/check-string-content-of-response-before-retrying-with-polly)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [Policy.HandleSyntax.cs](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Policy.HandleSyntax.cs) file then you can see how the `Handle<T>` methods have been defined:

```cs
public partial class Policy
{
    public static PolicyBuilder Handle<TException>() where TException : Exception
        => new PolicyBuilder(exception => exception is TException ? exception : null);

    public static PolicyBuilder Handle<TException>(Func<TException, bool> exceptionPredicate) where TException : Exception
        => new PolicyBuilder(exception => exception is TException texception && exceptionPredicate(texception) ? exception : null);
        
    ...
}

public partial class Policy<TResult>
{
    public static PolicyBuilder<TResult> Handle<TException>() where TException : Exception
        => new PolicyBuilder<TResult>(exception => exception is TException ? exception : null);

    public static PolicyBuilder<TResult> Handle<TException>(Func<TException, bool> exceptionPredicate) where TException : Exception
        => new PolicyBuilder<TResult>(exception => exception is TException texception && exceptionPredicate(texception) ? exception : null);
            
    ...
}
```

- All of the methods rely on the `PolicyBuilder` class, which has an [internal ctor](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/PolicyBuilder.cs#L11).

  - So, we can't use it in our custom code.
- Also notice that the `Policy` class [does not have a public ctor](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Policy.cs).

  - So, we can't create a `Policy` instance, that's why it does not make sense to create extension methods for the `Policy` class.

Here is one way to overcome on these limitations:

```cs
public static class PolicyExt
{
    public static PolicyBuilder HandleExcept<TException>() where TException : Exception
        => Policy.Handle((Exception exception) => exception is TException is false);

    public static PolicyBuilder HandleExcept<TException>(Func<TException, bool> exceptionPredicate) where TException : Exception
        => Policy.Handle((Exception exception) => exception is TException is false || exception is TException texception && !exceptionPredicate(texception));
}

public static class PolicyExt<TResult>
{
    public static PolicyBuilder<TResult> Handle<TException>() where TException : Exception
        => Policy<TResult>.Handle((Exception exception) => exception is TException is false);

    public static PolicyBuilder<TResult> Handle<TException>(Func<TException, bool> exceptionPredicate) where TException : Exception
        => Policy<TResult>.Handle((Exception exception) => exception is TException is false || exception is TException texception && !exceptionPredicate(texception));
}
```

And finally here is a quick test:

```cs
var policy = PolicyExt.HandleExcept<Exception>(ex => ex is NotSupportedException)
    .WaitAndRetry(2, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

//Or just:
//var policy = PolicyExt.HandleExcept<NotSupportedException>()
//    .WaitAndRetry(2, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

policy.Execute(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Have been called");
    throw new NotSupportedException();
});
```

Output:

```
Have been called
Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
```

- So, in case `NotSupportedException` the retry logic is not triggered.
- But if we execute the policy against the following delegate:

```cs
policy.Execute(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Have been called");
    throw new Exception("Custom");
});
```

Then the output will be the following:

```
Have been called
Have been called
Have been called
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Custom
```

So, the retry is triggered.