# Receiving error 'The request message was already sent' when using Polly

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I am currently using Polly to limit the number of requests I send. This is the policy I currently have:

```
private AsyncPolicyWrap<HttpResponseMessage> DefineAndRetrieveResiliencyStrategy()
{
    HttpStatusCode[] retryCodes = {
       HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
       HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
       HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout
    };
    
    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy
        .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(e => e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable || e.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(10,
            attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), (exception, calculatedWaitDuration) =>
            {
                _log.Info($"Bitfinex API server is throttling our requests. Automatically delaying for {calculatedWaitDuration.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            }
        );
    
    var circuitBreakerPolicyForRecoverable = Policy
        .Handle<HttpResponseException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => retryCodes.Contains(r.StatusCode))
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(
            handledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 3,
            durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
            onBreak: (outcome, breakDelay) =>
            {
                _log.Info($"Polly Circuit Breaker logging: Breaking the circuit for {breakDelay.TotalMilliseconds}ms due to: {outcome.Exception?.Message ?? outcome.Result.StatusCode.ToString()}");
                
            },
            onReset: () => _log.Info("Polly Circuit Breaker logging: Call ok... closed the circuit again"),
            onHalfOpen: () => _log.Info("Polly Circuit Breaker logging: Half-open: Next call is a trial")
        );
    
    return Policy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy, circuitBreakerPolicyForRecoverable);
}
```

I have the following request sender:

```
private async Task<string> SendRequest(GenericRequest request, string httpMethod, string publicKey, string privateKey)
{
    var resiliencyStrategy = DefineAndRetrieveResiliencyStrategy();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(httpMethod), request.request))
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        string json64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json64);

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.BitfinexUri);

        var hashMaker = new HMACSHA384(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey));
        byte[] hash = hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
        string signature = GetHexString(hash);
        
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-BFX-APIKEY", publicKey);
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-BFX-PAYLOAD", json64);
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-BFX-SIGNATURE", signature);
        
        var message = await resiliencyStrategy.ExecuteAsync(() => client.SendAsync(httpRequest));
        var response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return response;
    }
}
```

As soon as the code hits the `waitAndRetryPolicy` and awaits the required amount of time, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times.'

I understand that this is happening because I am sending the same HttpRequest again but shouldn't the Polly library handle such an issue?

Comment: Please prefer `await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` over `message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times.'

is [thrown by the internals of `HttpClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L636-L642) if you [call directly into any .SendAsync(...) overload with an HttpRequestMessage which has already been sent](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L398-L414).

If you are using .NET Core, the recommended solution is to use [Polly with HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory): this solves the above exception by executing the policy (for example retry) via a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/c38f9c1e04a380870f4ae5b16bbcd7e2e49854b4/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs#L74-L163) within `HttpClient`. It also solves the [socket-exhaustion problem](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) which can be caused by a frequent create/dispose of `HttpClient`, which the code posted in the question may be vulnerable to.

If you using .NET framework, the recommended solutions are:

- replicate the way HttpClientFactory places the policy in a DelegatingHandler; *or*
- refactor your code to manufacture a new instance of `HttpRequestMessage` (or clone the existing instance) within the code executed through the policy.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260060/retrying-httpclient-unsuccessful-requests) discusses the problem extensively and many variants on the above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you would split up your code into the following two functions:

```
private HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(GenericRequest request, string httpMethod, string publicKey, string privateKey)
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(httpMethod), request.request);
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-BFX-APIKEY", publicKey);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    string json64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-BFX-PAYLOAD", json64);

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json64);
    var hashMaker = new HMACSHA384(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey));
    byte[] hash = hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-BFX-SIGNATURE", GetHexString(hash));

    return httpRequest;
}
```

```
private async Task<string> SendRequest(GenericRequest request, string httpMethod, string publicKey, string privateKey)
{
    var message = await DefineAndRetrieveResiliencyStrategy().ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        var httpRequest = CreateRequest(request, httpMethod, publicKey, privateKey);
        await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    });
    return await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

then your problem would vanish.

- The `CreateRequest` is responsible to create a new `HttpRequestMessage` whenever it is called (either by the initial request or any further retry attempt)
- The `SendRequest` is responsible to decorate the downstream communication with the predefined strategy and parse the result of any
- The `HttpClient` setup should be done only once and reused many times

Answer (score 0):

with .NET Framework alternatively to make it generic you can clone request and store in contextData utilizing `IAsyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync` function second parameter `IDictionary<string, object> contextData`